# Does full text search works with characters?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have successfully created an `FTS` index on a column where we have stored the name of medicines e.g:

```
Amoxicillin 250mg capsules 21 capsule
Verapamil 160mg tablets 100 tablet
```

When I search with the parameters  `Amoxicillin`  or `tablets` it works fine.

But when I search for `'%Amoxi%'` or `blets` it doesn't come up with the answer. However the same keywords work with `Like` operator.

```
select * from AMPP as a
WHERE Contains(A.[NM] ,'%Amoxici%')
```

Above query has no results . however below query returns 140 rows in result.

```
select * from AMPP as a
WHERE Contains(A.[NM] ,'%Amoxicillin%')

select * from AMPP as a
WHERE a.nm like '%Amoxici%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CONTAINS and LIKE are two completely different beasts.

As it is a full text index search the wildcards (% %) become redundant.

For your query I belive you would need to do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AMPP AS A
WHERE CONTAINS(A.NM, '"Amoxici*"');
```

Refer to [MS Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)